# The else function does not appear even if the "if" conditions are not met

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement

The problem is when the bro says "no" the condition "if" always appears even if i use "else" or "elif", why? Isn't it supposed that if the input is something other than yes or yeah, is else what appears? pls help

ok here is my code:

```
# asking the bro
are_you_happy = input("You feel bad bro? ")

# psicological support loop haha
while are_you_happy.upper() == "YES" or "YEAH":
  print("*give him a hug*")
  better = input("you feel better bro? ")

  # he feel better boys :)
  if better.upper() == "YES" or "YEAH":
    print("i'm happy for you")
    break

  # he don't feel better :(
  elif better.upper() == "NO":
    more_support = input("do you want another hug? ")
    if more_support.upper() == "YES" or "YEAH":
        print("*give him a very huge hug")
        print("i hope you well bro")
        break
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4vCF.png)

Comment: `are_you_happy.upper() in ["YES", "YEAH"]:`. The issue is `or "YEAH"` is always true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, the expression:

```
something == "YES" or "YEAH"
```

is equivalent to:

```
(something == "YES") or ("YEAH")
```

And, since `"YEAH"` is a truthy value, this will *always* be true. The *right* way to use `or` in this case is with:

```
something == "YES" or something == "YEAH"
```

but you would be better off with the more Pyhtonic:

```
something in ["YES", "YEAH"]
```

Make sure you change all *three* of the problem lines in your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you state two possible conditions by using or, both should be compared to the condition, so, in your example you are using `are_you_happy.upper() == "YES" or "YEAH"` and your program is checking if are_you_happy is equal to YES, and that would return false and lead you to the else part, but, after the or you are having a YEAH that isn't being compared to anything, so it's as if you had `if "YEAH":` which will always return true, therefore, elif and else never run. Modify the or cases to: `if are_you_happy.upper() in ["YES","YEAH"]:` and so on.

Comment: If you type in `"YES" or "YEAH"` to your REPL, you'll get back `YES`. You need to use `... in ['YES", "YEAH"]`.

Comment: My bad, I'm quite new as well. Edited it, thank you.

Answer (score -2):

you refer "Yeah" always is true

while are_you_happy.upper() != "YES" or "YEAH":

change == to != as the above written